# Cannot exit full screen using programs

Tags: fullscreen

I've got a weird problem: whenever I use software that is full-screen Ubuntu gets stuck and I cannot exit those programs by any means.

I already tried the shortcuts: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to close it, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to shift to Desktop or Terminal, since I can't shift to Terminal I cannot kill the program from it, and I cannot exit the program trough its own exit option. Whenever this has happened I've just pressed the power button to turn off my computer, but it sucks not being able to use those programs.

This has happened to me while running A.D. 0 (that's a videogame) and two minimalistic text processors: PyRoom and FocusWriter. At first, I thought it was a FocusWriter bug, but then it happened running PyRoom, and after several (failed) attempts to exit PyRoom, I remembered it happened to me running A.D. 0 as well.

Comment: Have you tried F11 to exit full screen?

Answer (score 0):

As it happens this is a ["feature" of pyroom (review)](http://www.linuxinsider.com/story/75166.html) 
ctrl+super+D should show your desktop (super is penguin/windows key)
But this is disabled on purpose as part of eliminating distractions.
I'd say that the video game is accessing raw video mode. You might be able to get back by using keystroke ctrl+alt+F7 to return to your Desktop session, but the game may just take over.

The completeness of full-screen in Ubuntu can be disorienting until you grow accustom to it. In the standard Unity Desktop for Ubuntu, full screen mode apps can hide the window bar. Firefox by default does this and also the location bar and tabs but it all comes back when you point the mouse cursor near the top edge of the screen.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply.

I know it is a feature of pyroom. The problem that Ubuntu gets stuck there and I cannot by any mean exit or close fullscreen using programs. I have no problem with firefox tough. Maybe it happens with programs that block the launcher.

Neither ctrl+alt+F7 nor ctrl+super+D worked, I just tried them. It kind of locks the whole keayboard or something like that.

Comment: When this happens in Pyroom you can't exit using it's own exit option  but can still type and use other options ? Is this a laptop or desktop ? What keyboard? I assume you are using Unity Desktop , not xfce, Cinnamon, KDE or Gnome? ( add info to the original question)

Comment: I couldn't use any more options nor type. All I could do was moving the mouse pointer but that was all. It happened to me as well while running Awesomenauts and Tales of Maj'Eyal (both videogames that run fullscreened) as well as with the Ubuntu image visor in full screen mode.

This problem happened on a laptop using Unity Desktop.

Yesterday I updated my drivers to the latest and most of the packages that gave this trouble seem to work fine now (pyroom, focuswritter, and most videogames). It didn't fixed it with 0 A.D. tough.

Comment: Having it fixed with the drivers update made me think it could be a graphic board issue, however, it's just a feeling I get.

Well, I'm glad it's pretty much fixed. Now I can write without distractions :D

Thank's for the repplies. I would like to hear what you think about the problem and what you think may have been causing it.

Comment: Yes! graphics driver issue